# URL-кодирование строки в Android

Tags: java, android

```
String url = "http://site.ru/search?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(search.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Этот код вызывает ошибку UnsupportedEncodingException. Что здесь не так?

Comment: А можно лог ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

```
URLEncoder.encode(
    "urlParameterString",
    java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

Comment: `java.nio` рулит )

Comment: Google рулит ;)

Comment: С большой буквы G ;D

Comment: не работает( тоже самое

Comment: Посмотрите тут
[ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030059/url-decoding-unsupportedencodingexception-in-java)
[ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748440/recommended-method-for-handling-unsupportedencodingexception-from-string-getbyte)
[ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049524/is-java-utf-8-charset-exception-possible)